# .Where in list gives error for using dynamic types in 2sxc

Tags: c#, linq, 2sxc

I have this working code:

```
@{
      var ekgList = AsList(App.Data["Ekgs"]);
      foreach(var ekg in ekgList) {
          <div>
              @foreach (var entitiesFromSinusDataType in ekg.Sinus) {
                  if(entitiesFromSinusDataType.EntityId == Content.EntityId) {
                      <a>@ekg.ShortName</a>
                  }
              }
          </div>
     }
}
```

For what I can understand:

- ekgList is a list (standard 2sxc code for accessing data)
- ekg.Sinus is a field in Ekgs content type (Entity data type, multiple, which creates a list of entities from another content type,
  Sinus)
- Content.EntityId is an int, the same as entitiesFromSinusDataType.EntityId

There should be an easy way to remove the second loop and the "if", by placing a where clause in the first loop.
I'm trying this step by step, but as soon as I try this:

```
@{
      var ekgList = AsList(App.Data["Ekgs"]);
      foreach(var ekg in ekgList) {
          <div>
              @foreach (var entitiesFromSinusDataType in ekg.Sinus.Where(i => i.EntityId == Content.EntityId)) {
                  <a>@ekg.ShortName</a>
              }
          </div>
     }
}
```

I get this error:

```
CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

This seems to be caused by using dynamic types.

Is there some way to cast the lists into a non dynamic version of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the `ekg.Sinus` to `((IEnumerable<dynamic>)ekg.Sinus)` :

```
((IEnumerable<dynamic>)ekg.Sinus).Where(i => i.EntityId == Content.EntityId)
```

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler cannot guess that `ekg.Sinus` is a list - so LINQ extensions are not automatically resolved. Note that you can also do this since 2sxc 10.25:

```
AsList(ekg.Sinus).Where(...)
```

or in case that doesn't work (again sometimes the compiler can't guess everything) do:

```
AsList(ekg.Sinus as object).Where(...)
```

I also suggest you check out the LINQ tutorials https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/linq/home

Comment: AsList did not work. Object -> List does work, but it's double cast. Isn't the above sugestion of IEnumerable<dynamic> better?

Comment: It's basically identical - the `as object` doesn't really do anything, and `AsList(...)` won't convert anything that's already a list. My preference is AsList because it feels more readable.